# C# attributes and methods

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, attributes

Good day, everyone,
recently I've come across the Discord.NET Api and was in love with the way Commands were handled. Essentially, to add a new Command that is executed when you write `!ping`, you can do this:

```
[Command("ping")]
public async Task Ping()
{
    //some logic here
}
```

And I really liked the easy nature of integrating new commands in an already existing API. So I wanted to recreate what was going on. In the beginning I was absolutely confused by the introduction of metaprogramming, but now feel a little more comfortable, so I tried to start, and designed an Attribute that was only assignable to methods:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class Command : Attribute
    {
        
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Command(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
        public Command()
        {
            Name = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Basic idea then is, that when my Console gets a command, I can run a method that has the command attribute and the name of what was entered in the console. So when I enter "ping" in the console, the below method is going to be executed.

```
[Command("ping")]
public void Ping()
{
    //do sth 
}
```

Now to the complicated part. How do I find and especially run that method? That's where I'm stuck right now. I really don't find anything helpful about that question on the .Net documentary or here on stackoverflow. Here is my attempt anyway:

```
public void Handle(string command)
{
    var methods = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                  where t.GetCustomAttributes<Command>().Count() > 0
                  select t;
     //run method where command.name = ping
}
```

The idea behind that being, to iterate through all available methods in the assembly, and then putting those into a List of some kind and then executing the method that has the command.name of what was passed in as an argument to the Handle function. When I get that to work, I of course will initilaize the methods list in the constructor of that class and not everytime call it when Handle is called, but for simplicity in my question I formulated my question independent of that, to have my example minimal. The question now is, how do I iterate through all methods in my assembly, and save those with the command attribute into a collection, and how do I run a method that has a certain value for the command.Name property?
I'am kind of new to that whole reflection stuff, so if I did something else stupid or you have general tips on that topic please let me know!!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You're quite close.
1. You are searching for attributes on classes right now.
2. Once you have your [`MethodInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke?view=netframework-1.1) object, you can call the `Invoke(object, object[])` on it to actually make the call.

Comment: To start off, it's common to call your custom `Attribute` `CommandAttribute` (don't worry as an attribute you can still type `[Command("ping")]`). That said your method `public void Ping()` tells us this is a method that needs to be called on an instance of whatever class it's defined on. So where does that instance come from? Or was it intended to be `static`? Also you're getting close however you're now scanning for `GetTypes()` which are things like classes, enums etc not methods.

Comment: @Knoop so if i implement some kind of CommandBase, and let every Class that implements methods that shall be registered under the commandAttribute inherit from the CommandBase, I could theoretically find all classes that inherit from the CommandBase and than search for their methods tagged with the commandAttribute? How do I then run a command? Is my idea correct? How would I then search the assembly? It's so much, but I will experiment a little, thanks for the hint

Comment: Yes generally I would say it's a good idea to create some kind of way to distinct classes that have commands, however the actual way you do this depends on a lot of things. For example I could see scenario's where inside your commands you would need access to additional services (like database access etc). For this it would be preferred if you could integrate this in your Dependency Injection framework and use that to create the instances to run your commands on. Or you could require the methods to be `static` and not even use an instance at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a small demo application that should help you to complete your logic. Overall, of course, it still has room for improvement, but it works:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace DemoApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string command = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

            LogicProvider provider = new LogicProvider();
            MethodInfo method = provider.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault((item) => item.GetCustomAttribute<CommandAttribute>().Identifier == command);
            method?.Invoke(provider, null);
        }
    }

    public class LogicProvider
    {
        [Command("DemoCommand")]
        public void MyMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Here");
        }
    }

    public class CommandAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public CommandAttribute(string identifier)
        {
            this.Identifier = identifier;
        }

        public string Identifier { get; } = null;
    }
}
```

If *DemoCommand* is entered in the console, then a search is made in the *LogicProvider* for a matching method. If there is a match, it is executed.

The whole thing also works with methods that have parameters. In the case of method?.Invoke(), this can then be specified.

Comment: Thank you @Saber, that one long line is doing the job perfectly. I will try extend your solution for my needs but your idea is prettymuch perfect, thanks! So I can store methods as MethodInfo, and run them via .Invoke(). That's so neat!! The '?' in method?.Invoke means, that it's exclusively executed when method is not null, right?

Comment: Yes that's it, be aware that it is a relatively new feature, so if you happen to target older versions of the framework not supporting the latest versions of the language, you won't be able to use it.

Comment: @onefriendlyprogrammer You're very welcome, I´m happy to help. :) Yes, the question mark is nothing more than a shorthand for a NULL check. The logic should still be tightened up in many places (e.g. string comparison, upper/lower case, methods with parameters, etc.). But I have already used the basic concept many times and it works. If I can help in any way, just let me know ;)